# script src attribution sometimes doen't work in .php file

Tags: php, javascript, html, dom, syntax

i wrote like this as follow in a php file (for example: a.php)

```
<script src="scripts/a.js"></script>
<div>
 .....
</div>
```

I can guarantee that the path of js file is right, because i can see the js content in firebug HTML-view. However, in Script-view there isn't a.js. It seems that a.js has been added into the html but can't be loaded, but some other js files can be recognized. And if I paste the js content directly in the DOM, it works.

I'd like to know when  doesn't work and why? thanks a lot~

---

**Answer: There's some serious syntax errors in my js file. The error may be too serious for the browser to recognize it...**

Comment: does the console say anything? like a 404? or a parsing error? The tag may be in the DOM but the script might not be loaded.

Comment: no errors..console shows nothing.

Comment: how about the network tab? no failed scripts there?

Comment: it loads everything including the unworked js, return 304 not modified. no failed

Comment: what does this `a.js` contain? can you post? did you try putting an alert and see if it works?

Comment: it doesn't work. I wonder if there's something with the loading order of php and html dom?

Comment: I got it. There's some serious syntax errors in my js file. it is so serious that the browser cannot recognize it...

Comment: It's amazing how the console didn't see that.

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you a positive answer as there's very little details, but you should use an absolute path to your JavaScript.

```
<script src="/scripts/a.js"></script>
```

Comment: <script src="scripts/change_userinfo.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/locationselector_framework.js"></script>
<div id="_area"> ..
for example , like this, the first one doesn't work, the second one works.

Comment: Does your JavaScript console display any errors? If you'd like to post the link I'd be happy to take a quick look.

Comment: console shows nothing, just acts as if everything works well.